# Long return message when i send email using gmail smtp in localhost

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using `PHPmailer` library to send email from localhost using `wampServer`. I am using Gmail SMTP server.I can send email to my deserved mail address. But problem is, after sending the mail I got return message `email is sent` but at the same time, very long return message also appear and it takes very long time. Why is this long return message along with my return message?

[screen shot of the return  message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkrKu.jpg)

Comment: Please provide you code here...

Comment: @GyandeepSharma Its solved. thanks. Can you please tell me, if my code is very long how can i share the code on this site?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

`$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;`

```
 (0): Disable debugging (you can also leave this out completely, 0 is the default).
 (1): Output messages sent by the client.
 (2): as 1, plus responses received from the server (this is the most useful setting).
 (3): as 2, plus more information about the initial connection - this level can help diagnose STARTTLS failures.
 (4): as 3, plus even lower-level information, very verbose, don't use for debugging SMTP, only low-level problems.
```

Comment: Thanks it works.  But it is still taking a long time, why?